# Looking to remove both rows if duplicated in a column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I am attempting to create a new data frame without the rows of duplicated values in column "id"

I've tried some options however I would like to keep things consistent and take advantage of `dplyr`. I tried working with the `distinct()` function but to no avail.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(id = c("1-2", "1-3", "1-3", "1-4", 
"1-5", "1-7", "1-7", "1-7", "1-9", 
"1-22"), award_amount = c(3000, 596500, 1125000, 5881515, 
155555, 686500, 207718, 250000, 750000, 3500000)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

s4 <- df  %>% 
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) 
s4
```

I would like both rows containing duplicates in the "id" column to not exist in the final table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id    award_amount
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 1-2           3000
2 1-4        5881515
3 1-5         155555
4 1-9         750000
5 1-22       3500000
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use(`ungroup` as required):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!anyDuplicated(id))
 Groups:   id [5]
  id    award_amount
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 1-2           3000
2 1-4        5881515
3 1-5         155555
4 1-9         750000
5 1-22       3500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different way without grouping using a trick with `duplicated`. Checking duplicates from both ends of the vector means that all duplicates are flagged as `TRUE`. We can negate the result and then `filter` to the desired rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(id = c("1-2", "1-3", "1-3", "1-4", "1-5", "1-7", "1-7", "1-7", "1-9", "1-22"), award_amount = c(3000, 596500, 1125000, 5881515, 155555, 686500, 207718, 250000, 750000, 3500000)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   id    award_amount
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 1-2           3000
#> 2 1-4        5881515
#> 3 1-5         155555
#> 4 1-9         750000
#> 5 1-22       3500000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>